# Accessing K8S API Server running on Openstack behind a floating IP

Tags: kubernetes, proxy, openstack, rbac, kubernetes-apiserver

I have Kubernetes Master listening on Internal Openstack network address 192.168.6.6:6443. This machine has a floating IP associated for ssh based access (x.x.x.x) from my home. SSH received on the floating IP is sent to the internal IP. But this does not work for 6443 forwarding.

How do I access the K8S API server from my home when I can access the floating IP associated with the K8S master but not the internal IP on which the API server is listening.

I know the method of copying config file to your local machine but config files have the ip address on which master is listening and that ip is not accessible from outside Openstack.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this by reinstantiating the k8s cluster on OpenStack and providing the floating ip as "--apiserver-cert-extra-sans" parameter to kubeadm.

kubeadm init --apiserver-cert-extra-sans=

Answer (score 0):

### 1. Configure API Server IP

You need to replace the API server ip in the KUBE_CONFIG file with the floating IP.

### 2. Configure Security Group

Then, you need to add ingress rule which allows TCP 6443 port to the security group of the master node interface.
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did not know you could change the address on which the API server is listening. How is this done? Also, wouldn't this make the master inaccessible for worker nodes on openstack?

Comment: So the api server address in the kube_config file indicates just the address which the client will send request. That floating ip will be routed to the internal kube_api server ip which api server is listening. So I would say the listening ip is not changing.

And also in the cluster, the worker nodes have already been joined to the cluster using the api server address(internal). The address in the kube_config is only used for the kube client which you are using and not in the worker nodes.

Comment: Thanks again but this was the first thing I tried. I copied the config file from the k8s master to my laptop and changed the IP 192.168.6.6:6443 to <floating-ip>:6443. But running a kubectl command with this gives the error: "Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate is valid for 192.168.6.6, not <floating-ip>